# How to do back-end in ReactJS- (Is it possible)

Tags: reactjs, django, api, frontend, integration

I am new to web development I want to create an application  using React and Django but all tutorials show that by using REST API.

is there a way to use Django and react without REST API and perform CURD.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend also reading this blog post https://www.valentinog.com/blog/drf/, where Django and React are integrated via mini React apps inside Django templates.
I am not sure if it is the best approach, but may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

React JS is a frontend JavaScript library. Whatever data is received by React from the backend, it's supposed be in JSON format and Django, if used without REST FRAMEWORK, doesn't pass JSON objects. It passes Query sets instead which are not acceptable and iterable in React. So, you have to use Django REST Framework, which makes use of serialisation and deserialisation for CRUD operations and hence creating REST APIs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**No, it's not possible.**
Because even ReactJS is supposed to be on client side(Frontend). **npm run build** generates HTML/CSS/JS bundle for your app.
For backend, you might need node-express/Django rest... etc
[HERE](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-react-app-with-a-node-backend-the-complete-guide/) is complete guide to integrate your app.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do that with Django but in the end you need a API, no matter if it is REST or GraphQL because Django take care about the backend and React do all the stuff in the front end and you will need a way to connect both (and you do that by using an API)

I recommend you to use [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) if you want to use a REST API or Graphene if you want to use a GraphQL API, here is a very [cool tutorial](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-python/0-introduction/) to start with graphql.